# MYSQL - Advice on populating FIELD options from another TABLE COLUMN using ENUM

Tags: mysql, enums

I'm a MySql newbie so sorry if this has been asked before.

I am going round in circles trying to get a solution to this question.

I have a MySql database with two tables.

TERRITORIES

This table lists all nations of the world and has a column for listing the currency of each country.

CURRENCIES

This is essentially a "lookup" table including a country ID and a list of world currencies.

When inputting data into the TERRITORIES.currency cell I would like a drop-down list to appear from the CURRENCIES.country column.

I've spent hours googling to see if an ENUM field can call that data from the other table or whether one should use SET etc.

If anyone can assist me with reference to a good CLEAR tutorial on this issue I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I don't see the difference between territories and currencies but if there is one and you wish to populate currency from currencies then you need to select from currencies - enum is not going to do this. If you need to validate(which is what enum is used for) currency entered to territories then you should validate in your front end again selecting from currencies.

Comment: Thanks. However, I wasn't clear. I am not building a front end. I would like to know how to achieve this within the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be 2 things you want to happen 1) Populate 2) validate
For both triggers may be good for you.

```
delimiter $$
Create trigger t before insert on territories
for each row 
begin
 set new.currency = (Select currency from currencies where country = new.country);
end $$
delimiter ;
```

It doesn't then matter if an insert tries to insert to currency as well as country.

You also need an update trigger

```
delimiter $$
Create trigger t before update on territories
for each row 
begin
  set new.currency = (Select currency from currencies where country = new.country);
end $$
delimiter ;
```

To stop an update changing the currency to an invalid currency.